# Подгрузка img-файла на html-p

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеются две картинки, которые надо поставить рядом с кнопками (Выбрать и Отмена).

Подгрузить их не выходить. Сверяю путь и не пойму, как прописать корректно?

Фрагмент html:

```html
<div>
        <div class="b-toolbar__block_chevron ctrl_left">
            <a class="b-toolbar__item" onclick="OnValid()">
                <img alt="" class="b-ico b-ico_replace" src="/../Images/blank.gif" />
                <span class="b-toolbar__item__label">Выбрать</span> </a><a class="b-toolbar__item"
                    onclick="window.parent.ClosePopup();">
                    <img alt="" class="b-ico b-ico_cancel" src="/../Images/blank.gif" />
                    <span class="b-toolbar__item__label">Отмена</span> </a>
        </div>
```

Ключевая строка: src="/../Images/blank.gif" . Стало быть, путь к источнику указан неверно? Как же верно?

Дерево проекта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я так понимаю, нужно подняться на 2 уровня вверх `src="../../Images/blank.gif"`

Comment: Да, прописал, картинки с крестиками пропали, остался только текст. Однако , нужные картинки так и не появились.

Comment: Ну может в верстке дело и их прост не видно. А может картинки такие.

Comment: Аналогичный код использовался ранее в других местах. И работал. Значит, что-то не так в верстке, никак не найду.